# Model Change Detection: Object.observe Polyfill vs Angular Dirty Checking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, object.observe

Im wondering if anybody has done any benchmarking on polymer polyfill and angular dirty checking when it comes to model change detection.

Are these two performance checks 'apples to apples'?
http://jsperf.com/angularjs-digest/50
http://jsperf.com/polymer-dirtycheck/26

In the following comparison both frameworks need to register a watcher/observer and then the model is updated.
I can see how dirty checking when using polyfills is head to head in some browsers.

http://jsperf.com/polymer-comparison

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Well, http://jsperf.com/polymer-dirtycheck/26 is definitely comparing a method call to itself

Comment: http://jsperf.com/polymer-dirtycheck/25 this one seems to be evaluation when the model actually changes. isnt it?